# How to close current form and pass the string to the preform after click OK button

Tags: c#, winforms

In the Form1, it will pop-up the Form2 after click "Add".

```
private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();

        AddWinForm addWinForm = new AddWinForm();

        dr = addWinForm.ShowDialog();
        addWinForm.Show();
    }
```

What I want is that it will pass the input string and refresh the listbox in the Form1 and close the Form2 after click "OK" button. But it seems something wrong.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        mainForm.AddMessageInfo = textBoxAddWinForm.Text;
        mainForm.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to let Form1 know that the user pressed the `OK` button.

Form1:

```
private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddWinForm addWinForm = new AddWinForm();
    DialogResult dr = addWinForm.ShowDialog();

    if(dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string info = addWinForm.AddMessageInfo;

        // do something
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
public string AddMessageInfo { get; private set; }

private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddMessageInfo = textBoxAddWinForm.Text; // Set AddMessageInfo
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // Let parent form know you pressed OK
    this.Close(); // Close this form
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This not the elegant way to do it but it gets the job done.
Other way is you could use delegates to pass information from one form to another.

```
 Public class addWinForm : Form
    {
     ... 
      public string Answer { get { return answer;}}
      private string answer;

      private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this is supposed
            answer = "1111";
            Close();
        }
    }
public class MainForm : Form
{
    ....
    private AddWinForm addWinForm = null;    
    private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            addWinForm = new AddWinForm();

            addWinForm.ShowDialog();
            string answerAfterButtonOk = addWinForm.Answer;
            addWinForm.Dispose();
            addWinForm = null;
        }
}
```